# Remove/add img based on counter using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Basically, what I want to do is when a list item is clicked, an image is appended to the images div, and when it is toggled off, to remove the last image from the images div. So the more list item's are added, the more images are in the div. When the list items are all toggled off, the number of images should be reset back to normal.

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="images">
  <img src="#" />
  <img src="#" />
  <img src="#" />
  <img src="#" />
  <img src="#" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var count = 0;
$('#list a').on("click", function(event){
    count++;
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('added');
    var classname = $(this).parent().toggleClass('added');

    if (classname == '') {
      // remove image
    } else {
      //add image
    }

}
```

any ideas?

Comment: You don't appear to be adding list-items, the only effect is toggling the class-name of the `a` within a list-item; and, it *seems*, if the `a` has *no class-name* you're removing an image, otherwise appending an image. Could you clarify what you actually want to happen (clearly, and step-by-step)? Also, what's the `count` variable being used for? As it stands your question is unclear.

Comment: What does _When the list items are all toggled off_ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just loop through the image list to see if the source exists and leave classes out of it?  Something like this maybe?:

```
$('#list a').on("click", function(event){

    var src = $(this).attr('href'); // source of link clicked

    var addMe = 1;

    // loop through images list and look for clicked source
    $('.images img').each(function(i) {
        var $img = $(this);

        if ($img.attr('src') = src) { // found source matching <a href>
            $img.remove(); // remove the image
            addMe = 0; // stop image from adding
        } 
    });

    // if addme still = 1 append the html
    if (addMe) {
        var html = '<img src="'+src+'" />';
        $('.images').append(html);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an element has a class applied to it like:

```
if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('added')) {
  // remove image
} else {
  //add image
}
```

Comment: How does that relate to the question being asked? I'm not trying to be snide, or facetious, I'm just interested in what you think the question is (because I haven't, as yet, discerned what it might be). Also, surely it'd just as easy, and 'cheaper', with `this.className.indexOf('added') == -1`?

Comment: To me it looks like the OP is toggling as class then checking to see if the element in question has that particular class after the toggle. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call that *easier*, but I'd agree with cheaper.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point about the 'easier.' And that understanding seems perfectly valid in the face of zero clarity from the original question.